# pass parameters to SOAP request in mule esb

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio, mule-el, anypoint-studio

I have situation like on picture:

[image]

I configured request connector like i did in soap-ui, but I don't know how to build valid SOAP HTTP_Request with uri or query parameters from HTTP listener.

How can I pass those parameters to SOAP HTTP_Request?

**Edit:**
I know that i can put parameters into payload, how can i transform that payload into xml soap request? Is this a right way to do it or there is another way?

**Edit2:**

I switched to Web service consumer, but i have same problem, i don't know how to get data from http listener payload and map it to Web Service Consumer Request metadata.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

if you need to call an operation of a **Web Service** based on a **WSDL**, you need to use a **WS Consumer** block to call it, providing WSDL link in WS block as suggested by Ranveer. To map your input into WS Consumer you can use a **Datamapper** (Mule 3.6 or below) or a **Dataweave** (Mule 3.7+). I hope this helps.

Comment: I know there are 2 different ways of calling Web Service: over Http request and over WS Consumer, i think it doesn't matter which one is used -it is the same

Comment: If you use a WS Consumer with DataSense flag checked and a Datamapper or a Dataweave before, you will be able to see your XML input structure and pass correctly all parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If your SAOP message is single part then use web services connector and provide WSDL file link to it. It will configure automatic.

In http requester you can see add parameter button so add as much parameter as you doing in SOAPUI..

Comment: what do you mean by "single part"? My Soap request has 2 objects with parameters.

Comment: means that Soap request only have one tag header or body.

Answer (score -1):

Read through the following blog post. This provides with detailed information on consuming consuming a SOAP service via a Rest proxy.

http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/howto/rest-api-proxy-to-soap-webservice/

or

https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange#!/create-rest-api-proxy-to-soap-web-service

This should help.

Comment: @EngineerDollery The user has asked an abstract question. I was pointing him to a proper example to help. I could write a detailed example to help him. But why re-invent a wheel.

Comment: Because the links go stale and the answer becomes useless. It has a short shelf-life. This site is trying to build a reference for the future but link-only answers thwart that goal. In a day/week/month/year this answer will be meaningless because the content at the end of the links will have moved or been deleted. Anyone looking for an answer to this problem then will be SOL.